# JS CSS HTML - creating a button that maintains the same width independent of text amount

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a button that when clicked changes the background colour. However I would like the button to be in the centre of the page (have used position relative) however when I try to create a width for the button another box comes up with a thin border. I would like to have a button the same size and the text centered no matter what text (max 20 characters)

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
top{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.main{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
    border: black 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
  }
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colour Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
        <ul>Simple</ul>
        <ul>Hex</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">
        Background Colour
    </button>
    </div>
    <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction(){
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
let colorSindex = -1;
function myyFunction(){
  colorSindex +=1;
  if (colorSindex > colors.length-1) colorSindex = 0;
  document.querySelector('#btn').innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TRY CONSIDERING THIS ONE

**Might help you**

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
top{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.main{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
    border: black 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 40%;
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;

  }
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colour Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
        <ul>Simple</ul>
        <ul>Hex</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">
        Background Colour
    </button>
    </div>
    <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction(){
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
let colorSindex = -1;
function myyFunction(){
  colorSindex +=1;
  if (colorSindex > colors.length-1) colorSindex = 0;
  document.querySelector('#btn').innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @goosey9 you just need to set width and height of Button ID let me know if you find it help full !!

Comment: run in **full page** to se accurate results

Answer (score 0):

As I can check, you had applied a border to .main instead of #btn and that's why you were seeing a box around the button.

I made the .main a block element so it covers the whole width and gave the button element a fixed width of 30%.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
top{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: black 2px solid;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.main{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
    display: block; /* made it block to cover the whole width */
    position: relative;
    /* removed the border from here due to which you were seeing another box */
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#btn {
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 30%; /* gave the button a fix  width */
    border: black 1px solid;
  }
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colour Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>Colour Flipper</ul>
        <ul>Simple</ul>
        <ul>Hex</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">
        Background Colour
    </button>
    </div>
    <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
const colors = ["blue", "green", "yellow"];
let colorIndex = -1;

function myFunction(){
  colorIndex += 1;
  if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
let colorSindex = -1;
function myyFunction(){
  colorSindex +=1;
  if (colorSindex > colors.length-1) colorSindex = 0;
  document.querySelector('#btn').innerHTML = colors[colorSindex]
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I omitted the `display:inline-block` so `.main` takes the full width:

I also moved the `border: black 1px solid;`
 so it now belongs to the `#btn`.

I also gave `#btn` a fixed width.

```
    .main{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
    position: relative;
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;

}
#btn {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
          border: black 1px solid;
          width:30%;

  }
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. It had a box taking up the full width and the button content was only background colour

Answer (score -2):

I was able to do it like this:

```
 const colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    let colorIndex = -1;
    function myFunction(){
        colorIndex += 1;
        if (colorIndex > colours.length -1) colorIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = colours[colorIndex]
        document.getElementById("btn").style.width="9%";
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colourflipper.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction();myyFunction()">Background Colour</button>
    </body>
    <script src="colourflipper.js"></script>
    </html>

    button{
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-left: 48%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: does my solution helps you??

Comment: Just saw your solution looking now thanks XD

Comment: hey Yash, why is position: fixed; so important in this. For example if I use position relative it creates crossing borders and doesnt look nice.

Comment: **position: fixed;**  is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.

Comment: whereas **position: relative;**  is positioned relative to its normal position.
Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236505/discussion-between-yash-chitroda-and-goosey9).